# SQL Error converting data type varchar to float within CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Within a very large query I have this `Case` statement and I get an error message.

First, to get the percentages for the below `Case` statement, I'm doing this:

```
,   'YOY_ADV_COMPLEXPRD_AMTCHG'     = COALESCE((A.[Adv ComplexPrd Amnt] - B.[PREV12_Adv ComplexPrd Amnt]) / CAST(NULLIF(B.[PREV12_Adv ComplexPrd Amnt],0) AS FLOAT), 0)
,   'YOY_ADV_LVRG_INV_ETF_AMTCHG'   = COALESCE((A.[Adv Lvrg/Inv ETF Amnt] - B.[PREV12_ADV Lvrg/Inv ETF Amnt]) / CAST(NULLIF(B.[PREV12_ADV Lvrg/Inv ETF Amnt],0) AS FLOAT),0)
,   'YOY_ADV_NTRT_BDC_AMTCHG'       = COALESCE((A.[Adv NTRT_BDC Amnt] - B.[PREV12_ADV NTRT_BDC Amnt]) / CAST(NULLIF(B.[PREV12_ADV NTRT_BDC Amnt],0) AS FLOAT),0)
,   'YOY_ADV_STR_CD_AMTCHG'         = COALESCE((A.[Adv Str_CD Amnt] - B.[PREV12_ADV Str_CD Amnt]) / CAST(NULLIF(B.[PREV12_ADV Str_CD Amnt],0) AS FLOAT),0)
,   'YOY_ADV_STR_NOTE_AMTCHG'       = COALESCE((A.[Adv Str_Note Amnt] - B.[PREV12_ADV Str_Note Amnt]) / CAST(NULLIF(B.[PREV12_ADV Str_Note Amnt],0) AS FLOAT),0)
,   'YOY_ADV_OPTION_AMTCHG'         = COALESCE((A.[Adv Option Amnt] - B.[PREV12_ADV OPTION_AMT]) / CAST(NULLIF(B.[PREV12_ADV OPTION_AMT],0) AS FLOAT),0)
,   'YOY_ADV_VUL_AMTCHG'            = COALESCE((A.[Adv VUL Amnt] - B.[PREV12_ADV VUL Amnt]) / CAST(NULLIF(B.[PREV12_ADV VUL Amnt],0) AS FLOAT),0)
```

I get this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to float

```
,   'YOY_ADV_CMPLX_PRODIND'     = CASE WHEN C.YOY_ADV_COMPLEXPRD_AMTCHG >= '.30' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
,   'YOY_ADV_LVRG_INV_ETFIND'   = CASE WHEN C.YOY_ADV_LVRG_INV_ETF_AMTCHG >= '.30' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
,   'YOY_ADV_NTRT_BDCIND'       = CASE WHEN C.YOY_ADV_NTRT_BDC_AMTCHG >= '.30' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
,   'YOY_ADV_STR_CDIND'         = CASE WHEN C.YOY_ADV_STR_CD_AMTCHG >= '.30' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
,   'YOY_ADV_STR_NOTEIND'       = CASE WHEN C.YOY_ADV_STR_NOTE_AMTCHG >= '.30' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
,   'YOY_ADV_OPTIONIND'         = CASE WHEN C.YOY_ADV_OPTION_AMTCHG >= '.30' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
,   'YOY_ADV_LIFEIND'           = CASE WHEN C.YOY_ADV_VUL_AMTCHG >= '.30' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
```

I've tried casting the column to `Float`, which doesn't work and spent countless hours trying to figure this out.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Wat is the datatype of these columns? If they are float (which hopefully is the case), then they should be compared against numbers, not strings, like so: `C.YOY_ADV_COMPLEXPRD_AMTCHG >= 0.30`.

Comment: Yes, they are all float datatypes.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: To find the troublesome data, try running the following query for each referenced column: `SELECT * FROM Data WHERE (Value IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(Float, Value) IS NULL)`.

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also, the syntax with literal string aliases you are using is deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: You may ignore my last comment regarding TRY_CONVERT. (I'll leave it in case it still has use). Please confirm that your posted code is correct and not something you pulled while debugging. As posted, the only conversion I can see is the `'.30'` character values to float, presumably to match the comparison column type. Although not the best way to code the comparison, it should not throw an error. Either your posted code is not accurate or the error is comeing from somewhere else.

Comment: I ran the query without the strings, just against the numbers and I still get the same error message.  'Error converting data type varchar to float.'

Comment: Could the error be that the columns do have negative values as well?

Comment: @TN Sample data, desired results and attempt is required to get the FULL picture.   Look how long it took to what columns were what data types.   Even your first comment was going down the wrong path.    GMB's first comment should have nailed it, but apparently something else is going on here.   Are the columns truly float or are they actually strings?   Is the issue elsewhere ?

Comment: "Yes, they are all float datatypes".  If they were all floats, you wouldn't get the error you got. This error means one of your columns is actually varchar. I actually think the problem is not in the code you posted but in the other columns you haven't posted. The code you posted should never generate the error, since there would be no conversion needed to float.

Comment: My query is almost 5000 lines.  I can post the calculation I'm doing to get to this point.

Comment: The way i solve these problems is gradually comment out column by column until the error dissapears. This way, you know which column is the problem and can debug from there

Comment: @BIReportGuy - If you remove the suspect lines or replace them with fixed data like `, YOY_ADV_CMPLX_PRODIND = 'N'` do you still get the error? If not, evidence points to `YOY_ADV_COMPLEXPRD_AMTCHG` and/or others having character type and not float. (And I am referring to the **actual column type** and not the contents.) Try running the SELECT statements I suggested a few comments back to check for bad data.

Comment: 5000 lines !? What a Unit Testing nightmare.    In all my years, I've seen some pretty ugly structures/code , but nothing approaching 5000 lines.   I suspect this grew organically and overdue for a retool.

Comment: So, I am by NO means a SQL Server savant, but I don't see a syntax for `'literalname' = column-def`.  I see `@literal = columndef` to assign to a variable, but in the absence of anything else the statement `'YOY_ADV_COMPLEXPRD_AMTCHG'     = COALESCE((A.[Adv ComplexPrd Amnt]...` looks to ME like a boolean comparison between a literal character string and a floating point number.  Of course you get a conversion error when you try to convert the string literal  'YOY_ADV_COMPLEXPRD_AMTCHG' to floating point.  Can anyone else weigh in here?

Comment: Based on your updated post, I would now focus on the contents of `A.[Adv ComplexPrd Amnt]`, `B.[PREV12_Adv ComplexPrd Amnt]` and others in that group. One of those 
values may contain text that is triggering the error. I again suggest running the earlier posted SELECT against all of those column sources. *Please confirm having done so.*

Comment: @siggemannen Personally, I prefer alias = expression.  I find it more readable especially if you have a long expression.   That said, I'm not intolerant or judgmental of those who prefer the alternative.   Also, I would love to see some documentation regarding your claims of obsolete and/or depreciated.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti it's here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver16 Although now that i read it, it only deprecates 'string' = expression, so it seems both you and T-N are safe, i was mostly joking anyway. My boss also likes this version =)

Comment: **A note on debugging**: If removing certain expressions eliminate the error it might not be the removed expressions that were the cause of the error. It might actually be earlier expressions that are now no longer referenced.  (See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/A-JTxJ1I) that shows how a data conversion error is eliminated by not referencing the result.) This could be why the OP is focused on the wrong lines of code.

Comment: I changed all my columns to decimal and checked using the following code.    use tempdb
GO
EXECUTE sp_help #temp   I still get an error message "Error converting data type varchar to decimal"

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] here, @BIReportGuy . Very likely you'll find the problem during your time doing so, which is why it's something that is expected you to try to do before posting. If you do create a [mre] and don't understand why the error is happening though, then when you post it, we can *explain* the reason for the behaviour.

Comment: @siggemannen It was a swing at humor, I get that.   We're all guilty not landing the joke :)

Comment: @BIReportGuy - I am still awaiting confirmation that you have tested each of the supposedly numeric columns in your source data with queries like `SELECT * FROM Data WHERE (Value IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(Float, Value) IS NULL) OR (Value2 IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(Float, Value2) IS NULL) OR ...`. If calculations are dependent on earlier calculations, include alll of the contributing columns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this as answer because it's complicated to explain the comments.
What you can do is to test every column that participates in the FLOAT parts by doing this:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN [Adv VUL Amnt] IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,[Adv VUL Amnt]) IS NULL THEN  [Adv VUL Amnt] END) AS [NonFloat Adv VUL Amnt]
, MAX(CASE WHEN [SomeOtherColumn] IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,[SomeOtherColumn]) IS NULL THEN  [SomeOtherColumn] END) AS [NonFloat SomeOtherColumn]
-- Repeat with other columns
from yourlongselect
```

If this finds any column that cannot be converted to float, it will display this column value. Otherwise it will display NULL.

One potential source of your problem is that your NVARCHARs are numbers like: "100,30". SQL Server can only convert "100.30" etc.